# Decidability of the language of a regular expression being a subset of a given context free language

Tags: context-free, regular-expressions, decidability

Let L be a language of pairs $\langle R,G\rangle$, with the first element being a regex and the second being a CFG.
Is it decidable that G accepts whatever the regular expression does? In other words, is it decidable to say if $L(R)\subseteq L(G)$?

Comment: What happens if we take $R = \Sigma^*$?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Context-free_language#Decidability